# How to set nested mapping for elastic search index using Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to leverage nested object indexing in Elastic Search. I know how to do that with PUT requests through curl (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html)  but I would like to do that through Java API instead.

Here is how I create dynamically my index

```
    public void index(AnObject obj){
        Client client = elasticService.getES();
        // generate json
        if (client != null){
            try {
                byte[] json = JSON.serializeAsBytes(obj);
                IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("titan", "objIndex", obj.getUuid())
                        .setSource(json)
                        .get();
            } catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is how I update it

```
    public void updateIndex(AnObject obj){
        Client client = elasticService.getES();
        // generate json
        if (client != null){
            try {
                byte[] json = JSON.serializeAsBytes(obj);
                UpdateResponse response = client.prepareUpdate("titan", "objIndex", obj.getUuid())
                        .setDoc(json)
                        .get();
            } catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a way to set my index through Java so that specific or all of the embedded objects are mapped as nested

If that is not possible is it possible to configure Elastic search default mapping to index everything as datatype nested?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!